# Why were there no American women in the Revenant?

Tags: the-revenant

In The Revenant we see native women in the village formed by American soldiers, but why were there no American women brought?

Comment: I have a similar question - why are there *native* women in the village? They didn't appear to be under duress.

Comment: What do you mean by "native women" and "American women"?

Answer (score 9):

The name of the fort was Fort Kiowa (originally named Fort Lookout).  Numerous forts of these types began to appear after Thomas Jefferson completed the Louisiana Purchase in 1803.  Jefferson opened up a large portion of the new land to the America fur traders where Native Americans could meet at these forts and exchange furs for various goods.

The American men who occupied the forts were mainly made up of ex-military and private traders.  American Women were not allowed in the military and the harshness of the environment was considered too extreme for the "delicate" ladies of America, thus very few if not any women were brought to the forts.

In 1827, Bernarde Pratte made improvements to the fort and turned it into a major trading post for Native Americans.  Order was kept as best as it could, this is why the natives did not seem to be under duress.  If the natives were hassled and felt unsafe, there would be no business to conduct.